# Decide whether exists such a rational number alpha.

Tags: trigonometry

Decide whether exists such a rational number alpha that ctg (alpha*Pi) = 1/sqrt(3).
(sqrt means square root of 3). 
Thanks for any response.

Comment: Decided. And you're welcome!

Comment: You shouldn't just copy/paste homework problems here.  Give the problem, then show what you've come up with so far, and/or what particular issue you're struggling with.  We're not here to do your homework for you, but many of us would be happy to help you if you demonstrate some effort.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Have you checked the special triangles yet?

Comment: Ok, thank you very much :)